# Running a thread's run() method after a thread has completed

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I am trying to understand the state of a Thread object after the thread has completed. I read in a book that once a thread has completed its run() method, the thread object will still be a valid object on the head and can still be used as an instance object and you can still call methods on it. I decided to try this with the following example:

```
class DieThread implements Runnable{

    int y = 0;

    public void run(){
        for(int x=0; x<100; x++){
            System.out.println("             " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            System.out.println("y is " + y);
            y++;
            System.out.println("y is " + y);
        }
    }   
}

class ZiggyTest2{
    public static void main(String[] args){     

        DieThread d = new DieThread();

        Thread a = new Thread(d);
        Thread b = new Thread(d);
        Thread c = new Thread(d);

        a.start();
        b.start();
        c.start();

        try{
            a.join();
            b.join();
            c.join();
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }

        System.out.println("Running C's Run");
        c.run();        
    }
}
```

main() waits for the other 3 threads to complete by using join(). It then call c's run() method but for some reason it is not printing out anything from the run() method. Here is the last few lines of the output after i run the above program.

```
y is 287
y is 287
y is 288
y is 289
             Thread-1
             Thread-0
y is 289
y is 289
y is 290
y is 291
             Thread-1
             Thread-0
y is 291
y is 291
y is 292
y is 293
             Thread-1
             Thread-0
y is 293
y is 293
y is 294
y is 295
             Thread-0
y is 295
y is 296
             Thread-0
y is 296
y is 297
             Thread-0
y is 297
y is 298
             Thread-0
y is 298
y is 299
             Thread-0
y is 299
y is 300
Running C's Run
```

Even though the thread has completed, i was expecting the value of y to be 400 because of the c.run() call.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you didn't want to call d.run()?  Also, I'm surprised nothing broke as you had 3 threads incrementing the same variable with no locks in place.

Comment: Yes i wanted to run the thread object after it has completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for what you are observing is buried in the implementation of the `Thread` class.

When you call `c.run()` you are calling the `run` method on the thread object.  This is specified as calling the `run` method of the `target` object (i.e. the runnable supplied in the `Thread` constructor) if it is not `null`.  If `target` is `null` then the `Thread.run()` method does nothing.

OK, so you supplied a non-null `target`.

In fact, when a `Thread` finishes, the `Thread.exit()` method is called to clean up.  And one of the things that the cleanup does is to assign `null` to `target`.  (The code has a comment about needing to aggressively clear references, and a bug id.  Unfortunately, the corresponding bug report is missing, so it is not possible to know the real reason(s) that they do this.)

Anyway, the bottom line is that you can't rerun the target object's `run()` method by calling `Thread.run()`.  But you can call the target object's `run()` method directly ... if you have the target reference.

Comment: If the Thread.exit will assign null to the target, wouldnt calling the target's run method cause a NullPointerException? I just tried calling d.run() after the threads completed but didnt get a NullPointerException even though at this point the object should be null.

Comment: You won't get an NPE.  Read my 2nd paragraph again ... in particular, what it says about the case where `target` is `null`.  Better yet, look at the source code of the Thread class yourself.

Comment: *so it is not possible to know the real reason(s) that they do this* >> Stephen, the bug is from 1.0.2, since Oracle took over, they removed *a lot* of bug references. I clearly remember the code back in '99, still the same. Either way, the aggressive removal was helping the gc due to thread leaking and other stuff. Now it's still cool as sometimes the threads are still leaked.

Comment: @ziggy, you can rerun the thread in UnhandledExceptionHandler, though

Comment: @bestsss - that was what I thought.  But I wondered if there were other reasons too.

Comment: small trick, google cache keeps the original stuff: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:W0_scoXkARAJ:bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do%3Fbug_id%3D4006245+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk

Answer (score 3):

If you extend the Thread class, it'd work. Now it checks the `Runnable` target which is `null` after Thread.exit()

Answer (score 1):

Synchronize access to the state of the object `DieThread`

```
synchronized(this) {
    System.out.println("             " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    System.out.println("y is " + y);
    y++;
    System.out.println("y is " + y);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I was not really worried about the state of the object. I am more interested in what happens after the threads have completed being a thread.